# What is the origin of the name Hermitian and Unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, math-history

> A matrix $H$ is Hermitian if $H ^\dagger = H$. A matrix $U$ is Unitary if $U^\dagger=U^{-1}$.

My question is:

1. Why do we name matrices of such properties Hermitian and Unitary? These names are non-intuitive and have nothing to do with these properties.
2. Who named them?
3. Possible citation of first appearance in paper?

Comment: Hermitian is for Charles Hermite (1822-1901), french mathematician. $U$ is unitary because $U^\dagger\circ U=U\circ U^\dagger=I$

Answer (score 6):

Hermitian is because Charles Hermite. [List of things named after Charles Hermite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_things_named_after_Charles_Hermite). Unitary is because it is an extension of the concept of unit complex number.

Comment: Also for "first appearences" there's a great website (http://jeff560.tripod.com/h.html, e.g. lists "Hermitian Matrix")

Comment: Bad idea to name it after Hermite! I would call it adjoint-invariant !

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thank you so much!

Comment: @Rescy_ The usage is that things often take names after the people that studied them first... whether other names would be clearer or not. (The worst example I know of is Poisson Binomial Distributions and Poisson distributions, that share a name but are not related at all...)

Comment: And how should be named  a diophantine equation? the Hamiltonian? the Lagrangian, wronskian? A Riemannian manifold? How should I be named myself? :o)

Comment: @Bernard: By the way, I heard, once, Rajagopalan said "my spaces" (not as famous as those of Hilbert or Banach, but  Rajagopalan's spaces existent in some topological and analytical papers).

Comment: @Piquito: Yes, I once wondered if  Jordan called  what is now known as Jordan normal form ‘ the Form of Myself’…

Comment: @Bernard: Most likely, I think, it is that Jordan form appeared in the mathematical language when Jordan was already an honorable deceased.